mod_pagespeed is breaking a CSS clip-path resource url
I have a CSS rule:
clip-path: url(#tabCorners);
Which is pointing at an SVG  clipPath with id 'tabCorners' but it's being rewritten by pagespeed to something like:
clip-path: url(includes/style.css#tabCorners);.
Is there a way to stop this from happening? I need pagespeed running on the rest of the CSS file. I'm running version 1.13.35.2-0.

I eventually solved this by adding .. in front of the url to point it at the active directory. Pagespeed still rewrites it but it correctly rewrites to /mypage/#corners now.
